# Pull-down resistor value for interrupts

Tags: arduino-nano, interrupt

I wonder how to calculate pulldown resistor to make interrupt work?
I need to connect 5 buttons to A0 and get pressing event via interrupts.
Using different resistors, finally, I made work only 4 buttons. On 5th interrupt does not fire.
Currently I use the following resistors for the buttons:

```
R1      Vout
0       5,00
2,7K    4,45
5K      3,70
10K     2,77
22K     1,78
```

And Pulldown Resistor = 22K.

If pulldown Resistor = 10K I can get event for 1-3 button only.
Looks like the voltage 1,78V is quite low.
But I’d liked make it work with 1V at most.
I use RISING mode.

PS. Arduino Nano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino running at 5V needs at least 3.0V on the pin to read it as rising high.  You probably want to go a little more than that.  So that means your lowest voltage has to be like 3.3V or so.

Note that the analog pins don't have an external interrupt, you'll have to use pin change interrupts and then read with analogRead in the ISR.  So you can't use "RISING".  The pin change interrupts act on any edge.  So they'll trigger when falling as well.

That's a pretty poor way to handle these buttons.  Normally one would just poll buttons like this.  If your loop takes so long that you might miss a human pressing a button then perhaps you should look at that instead.